# extract the a field value with same name from JSON using JMeter

Tags: jmeter

In the JSON response I have multiple fields with same name inside different tags . But I need to fetch the  from that tag where  matches the number I want. Say in the below examplele I want to fetch the value "(786)402-9010" when customerPpid=467133011

[{"oopId":"110034477","timestamp":"3698652681958","targetType":"TMTroubleCall","billAccount":"3655732026","customerFormattedPhoneNumber":"(786)505-2911","customerIsRequestingCallBack":"false","customerPpid":"609188407","acceptTime":"03/16/2018 11:31:00","originator":"DPH0GNL","priorityForDisplay":"3","remarks":"test","ddbKey":"8614147890T","displayType":"SNCU","parentFplId":"268224478","parentActualDeviceType":"TXU","parentDdbKey":"8614147890T","parentTroubleCoordinateX":"863634","parentTroubleCoordinateY":"459622","parentPreviousProtectiveDeviceStack":"268221704,23282601,23281142","toldItr":"03/16/2018 14:30:00","toldMode":"N","ticketCallComplaints":[{"componentId":"1685289","description":"No Current"}],"customerLanguageMenuOption":"1"},

{"oopId":"114249429","timestamp":"3698652636567","targetType":"TMTroubleCall","billAccount":"6182150000","customerFormattedPhoneNumber":"(786)402-9010","customerIsRequestingCallBack":"false","customerPpid":"467133011","acceptTime":"03/16/2018 11:31:00","attachTime":"03/16/2018 11:31:00","originator":"DPH0GNL","priorityForDisplay":"3","remarks":"testing","ddbKey":"8614154820T","displayType":"SNCU","parentFplId":"268224477","parentActualDeviceType":"TXU","parentDdbKey":"8614154820T","parentTroubleCoordinateX":"864084","parentTroubleCoordinateY":"459307","parentPreviousProtectiveDeviceStack":"268221704,23282601,23281142","toldItr":"03/16/2018 14:30:00","toldMode":"N","ticketCallComplaints":[{"componentId":"1685289","description":"No Current"},{"componentId":"4063885","description":"Customer checked breaker"}],"customerLanguageMenuOption":"1"},

how should i do it?

Answer (score 0):

1. Add [JSON Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) as a child of the request which returns the above JSON
2. Configure it as follows:

   - Names of created variables: anything meaningful, i.e. `phone`
   - JSON Path Expressions:

     `$..[?(@.customerPpid == '467133011')].customerFormattedPhoneNumber`

     [image: JMeter JSON Path Extractor]
3. That's it, now you should be able to access the extracted value as `${phone}` where required.

Demo:

[image: JMeter Debug JSON Path]

References:

- [JSON Path Operators](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath#operators)
- [JMeter's JSON Path Extractor Plugin - Advanced Usage Scenarios](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/advanced-usage-json-path-extractor-jmeter)

Answer (score 0):

Use the following Json path expression

```
$..[?(@.customerPpid=="467133011")].customerFormattedPhoneNumber
```

Add a JSON extractor to the request as shown in the screenshot below

[image]
[image]

Please follow this [Link](https://www.redline13.com/blog/2016/01/jmeter-extract-and-re-use-as-variable/)  for more info on extracting variables

Jmeter [Json Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor)